# Use MySQL workbench to create tables and data for rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Can I use MySQL Workbench to create the tables and add data then import / connect that into my Rails app? My Rails app is already connected to MySQL. I am just wondering if I create tables in MySQL Workbench through the app_development schema if that will sync over to my Rails project or not and if there's a way to check to see if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

to generate schema.rb from an existing database.

Having schema.rb, you can generate an empty initial migration and put create_table and other statements from generated schema there. Doing this will allow you to use all the relevant rake tasks just as if you developed your database "the Rails way" — via a series of migrations.